# combining codes in one anonymous block

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help in combining my three codes in one anonymous block and also I need to put a substitution value that a user will use. any idea how I can do that ?? I am using oracle 10g express, here are my codes:

CODE 1:  Display department name and number of employees per department for every department that is in "Americas".

```
select department_name, count(employee_id) "number of employees"
from employees, departments, locations, countries, regions
where employees.DEPARTMENT_ID = departments.DEPARTMENT_ID 
AND departments.location_ID = locations.location_ID 
AND locations.country_ID = countries.country_ID 
AND countries.region_ID = regions.region_ID 
AND regions.region_name = 'Americas'
group by department_name
```

---

CODE 2: What are the average salaries per position?

```
SELECT job_ID, AVG(salary) as "avg salary"
FROM employees
GROUP BY job_ID
```

---

CODE 3:What are the average salaries per department?

```
SELECT department_ID, AVG(salary) as "avg salary"
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining completely different datasets into a single block is not possible in Oracle. Anonymous blocks are for executing a series of PL/SQL commands. A query (i.e. anything that returns back a result set, ex: `SELECT ...`)can only return a single result so it would need to be three separate queries.

If you're using `SQL*Plus` all of this can be done from the command line and/or with a `.sql`script file. You can also specify parameters on the command line as well (I couldn't tell if thats what you meant for the first query but I added it anyway).

## Script (`foo.sql`):

```
-- Set page size to something larger than the expected result set.
-- NOTE: You don't want to put 0 (unlimited) as it supresses the column headers.
SET pagesize 50000

-- Get the parameter from the command line:
VAR region VARCHAR2(256)
EXEC :region := '&1'

SELECT 'Processing for region: ' || :region
FROM dual;

-- Query 1
promp "Employee detail in specified region:"
select department_name, count(employee_id) "number of employees"
from HR.employees, HR.departments, HR.locations, HR.countries, HR.regions
where employees.DEPARTMENT_ID = departments.DEPARTMENT_ID
AND departments.location_ID = locations.location_ID
AND locations.country_ID = countries.country_ID
AND countries.region_ID = regions.region_ID
AND regions.region_name = :region
group by department_name
;


-- Query 2:
promp "Average salary by position:"
SELECT job_ID, AVG(salary) as "avg salary"
FROM HR.employees
GROUP BY job_ID;


-- Query 3:
promp "Average salaries by department:"
SELECT department_ID, AVG(salary) as "avg salary"
FROM HR.employees
GROUP BY department_ID;

exit
```

## Output:

```
$ sqlplus myuser/mypass@lvm01xe @sample.sql Americas

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sun Nov 18 09:11:11 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


'PROCESSINGFORREGION:'||:REGION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Processing for region: Americas

"Employee detail in specified region:"

DEPARTMENT_NAME                number of employees
------------------------------ -------------------
Administration                                   1
Accounting                                       2
IT                                               5
Purchasing                                       6
Executive                                        3
Shipping                                        45
Finance                                          6
Marketing                                        2

8 rows selected.

"Average salary by position:"

JOB_ID     avg salary
---------- ----------
IT_PROG          5760
AC_MGR          12000
AC_ACCOUNT       8300
ST_MAN           7280
PU_MAN          11000
AD_ASST          4400
AD_VP           17000
SH_CLERK         3215
FI_ACCOUNT       7920
FI_MGR          12000
PU_CLERK         2780
SA_MAN          12200
MK_MAN          13000
PR_REP          10000
AD_PRES         24000
SA_REP           8350
MK_REP           6000
ST_CLERK         2785
HR_REP           6500

19 rows selected.

"Average salaries by department:"

DEPARTMENT_ID avg salary
------------- ----------
          100       8600
           30       4150
                    7000
           90 19333.3333
           20       9500
           70      10000
          110      10150
           50 3475.55556
           80 8955.88235
           40       6500
           60       5760
           10       4400

12 rows selected.

Disconnected from Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, anything which is aggregated by the same yardstick *can* be combined easily.  Hence you can merge the third query with your first one like this:

```
select department_name
       , count(employee_id) as "number of employees"
       , avg(salary) as "avg salary"
from employees, departments, locations, countries, regions
where employees.DEPARTMENT_ID = departments.DEPARTMENT_ID 
AND departments.location_ID = locations.location_ID 
AND locations.country_ID = countries.country_ID 
AND countries.region_ID = regions.region_ID 
AND regions.region_name = :region_name
group by department_name
```

I have adapted your code to pass in a bind variable, `:region_name`.  There are various way of specifying variables in Apex.  [Find out more](http://www.talkapex.com/2011/01/variables-in-apex.html).

There is no meaningful way of including your second query.  The values for JOB_ID cross the values of DEPARTMENT_ID, so there's no common key to join on.